# Is it normal for memory warnings to disappear?

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-management

I've had lots of problems getting a simple UIImagePicker working (see my other posts), and I've been getting memory warning notifications after taking a picture and before I even get a chance to dismiss the UIImagePicker

Now, however... I've loaded up my app in Xcode today and all is working fine. Can't get the memory warning at all, under the same build settings etc.

My question is.. is this normal? Perhaps it was cleared by an iPhone restart, or XCode restart. Or should I be worried that I've still got a hidden memory warning, only now it's hiding from me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, very normal.  memory is used by lots of background tasks on the phone, so it really depends what your email client is doing, whether you're installing apps in the background, and lots more.

Comment: This is such a relief. I was convinced for ages that I was doing something majorly wrong!

Answer (score 1):

It also depends a lot on the device you're testing on too. For example, if you're testing on an iPhone 2G, you'll have a significantly lower amount of memory to play with than if you were testing on a 3GS for example.

Depending on what kind of requirements your app has, and what choices you're making in terms of what to target (3.0 only? 3G upwards, etc) its best to always test on the least capable device so that you can get an accurate idea of how the app will perform on that device.